# External Safari link or UIWebview?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Im creating an App which *needs* to link to a PDF which is stored online (its far too big to bundle with the app). Ive submitted the app to the AppStore, but it got rejected when I loaded the pdf into a UIWebview. So I changed this to loading it into Safari, but this also got rejected!

Does anybody know of an acceptable way of linking to a PDF on the internet from an App?

**Addition**

The reason from Apple for the loading in Safari is:

```
We found the following issues with the user interface of your app: 

When tapping on various tabs, it opens a web page in mobile Safari.
```

Comment: What was the reason given by Apple for rejection? Please place those words along with question.

Comment: does the app force a re-download of the PDF every time you go to read it... even if there are no changes from the previous load?

Comment: @Mrunal please see the additions in the main post.

Comment: @D80Buckeye I only know of how to load the item from the internet URL, so im guessing it has to re-download it. Although Apple dont know this, the file will actually rarely be opened - it just needs to be there as a reference in rare cases.

Comment: what was the original rejection? I'd have to assume based on your question that this was the latter rejection.

Comment: @D80Buckeye It was along the lines of "a section of the app only contains PDFs" Not 100% sure of the wording but it was to that effect. And I know it only contains PDF's - its a reference section of the app linking to NHS authorised guidance notes on drugs, so they are vitally important!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this might be the reason (Not sure):

If you refer [**App Store Review Guidelines**](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html), in that **2.12** says:

> Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected.

So instead of opening that into Safari, try using a separate UIViewController with UIWebView in that. And open your pdf web link over there inside the application itself. *Do not redirect user to Safari browser unnecessarily.*

As per Apple report provided by you and Review Guidelines, I guess this might be the cause of rejection.

To make sure, you can comment over the mail which you have got with app rejection notification. And ask to Apple itself regarding the issue and solution as well. They normally do reply.

Comment: Thanks - useful info. When you say "comment over the mail which you have got with app rejection notification" , do you mean reply to the email, or dispute the rejection and ask them in that? I dont want to dispute the fact (as its obviously not what they want), I just want a more concrete reason so I know how to resolve it!

Comment: Reply to same email. I am not sure because long back one of my app got rejected and had communication with Apple regarding more clarification. But right now I can't remember whether I have replied to the same email or asked to some other mail id. Try with replying that mail - if they have not mentioned in mail "Do not reply to this".

Comment: First try using UIWebView, and display those pdf weblinks in application itself. I guess that will be allowed.